# @GetMapping not produces response content type application/json

Tags: spring, swagger

I'm developing an API Rest with Spring 4 and annotations swagger. Until now I was using
`'@RequestMapping(value = "/myapi/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")'`, but I want to use the reduced version with GET:
`@GetMapping("/myapi/{id}")`.
The problem is that swagger is not showing correctly the response content type:
Instead of it, I get the following:

> response content type */*

I have tried adding an HttpHeaders object to the response entity but not works.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you added the produes to the `GetMapping`?

Comment: @GetMapping only supports the uri parameter

Comment: No it doesn't. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html

Comment: Ok Sorry Darren. It works!

Answer (score 27):

Need to add the same optional params to the `GetMapping` as your `RequestMapping`.

`@GetMapping(value = "/myapi/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`